# I want the station name to be changed when user clicks play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the fiddle all ready to go I just need help with the jquery/javascript part. What I want is to have the record name/station title change when the user clicks on the play button they find on hovering over the album cover. I also want the record/vinyl in the "player" box to start spinning. Right now it spins on hover but I want to change that.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/1/

and here is just the html code because the css is kinda long!

```
   <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="grid_6 alpha"><!-- record, overflow:hidden -->
            <div id="player">
            <div id="recordbox">
            <div class="record2">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bars-box">
            <div class="player-box">
            <div id="title-player">Now playing:</div><br><strong><span class="player-station">Groove Salad</span></strong>
```

```
<div class="bars">
                        <div class="bar-1"></div>
                        <div class="bar-2"></div>
                        <div class="bar-3"></div>
                        <div class="bar-4"></div>
                        <div class="bar-5"></div>
                        <div class="bar-6"></div>
                        <div class="bar-7"></div>
                        <div class="bar-8"></div>
                        <div class="bar-9"></div>
                        <div class="bar-10"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

    <div class="grid_3">
    <div class="album">
    <div class="record">
    </div>
    <div class="recordsinfo"><p class="recordinfo">A nicely chilled plate of ambient/downtempo beats and grooves.</p>
    <a class="play" href="#">Play</a>
    </div>
    <div class="salad"><!-- sleeve -->
    <h3>Groove Salad</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="grid_3 omega">
    <div class="album">
    <div class="record">
    </div>
    <div class="recordsinfo"><p class="recordinfo">Sensuous and mellow vocals, mostly female, with an electronic influence.</p>
    <a class="play" href="#">Play</a>
    </div>
    <div class="lush"><!-- sleeve -->
    <h3>Lush</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(function(){
    var station = $('.player-station');
    $('.play').click(function(){
        station.text($(this).closest('.album').find('h3').text());
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/3/

For spinning you can use: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: Did you see that when you hover over it, it starts spinning? I just want to move the spinning to when the user clicks on play

Comment: @benlevywebdesign here is example with play and stop buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/6/

Comment: So now I just have to make the play from the changing names also start the spinning, seems easy I think?

Comment: @benlevywebdesign yes, just change css.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to add some other text but can't seem to get that part working http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/8/
I haven't worked on the spinning yet so don't worry about that yet! Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17890/discussion-between-benlevywebdesign-and-webdeveloper)

Answer (score -1):

So, first thing is first... you need to read up on the use of an ID versus the use of a Class. To put it a bit simply:

- ID = Unique identifier for an element
- Class = Identifier for a series of elements

The reason I bring this up is because you have odd naming conventions like `class="lush"` which don't make sense. That should be an id, and the class should be something like "sleeve".

Anyway, here's the updated code and fiddle. Yes, you can make it a bit more condensed (not set a var for the title), but I wanted to spread it out so you could see the code a little better. If you have questions, let me know.

```
$('a.play').click(function() {

    var title = $(this).closest('.album').find('.album-title');

    $('span.player-station').text($(title).text());

});​
```

I also added a class to the h3 tags, just so you didn't run into any issues down the road:

```
<h3 class="album-title">Lush</h3>
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7txt3/4/